# Build React Native iOS App for Facebook App Review

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I have generated 2 or 3 builds following the Facebook app review instructions for iOS generating the ZIP file from the DerivedData and still, Facebook declines the app every time because they cannot run the zip file. That is the only thing they say.

If I drag and drop the file in my simulator, it works fine. It installs the app. I modified the schema to build for release when I build so the cache data has the compiled JS bundle. I even tried it in a clean simulator.

Any other particular detail I am missing? Facebook telling you only "zip file does not work" really does not help at all.

I am using xCode 8.

Comment: any luck with this @sfratini? I also just submitted using the same steps.

Comment: So i got a response saying something related to the internal app so I guess it worked. I didn't do anything different. The only thing that I can think of is that if you drag and drop the zip file to the emulator it just decompress it. You have to throw the .app. maybe Facebook guys were complaining about that.

Comment: I still dont have it approved

Comment: that's insane... will get back once they've reviewed our app

Comment: @Roosevelt mine got rejected again because I am not using the correct app ID in the login button...which clearly I am. This is ridiculous. Did you have any luck?

Comment: yeah I just got a response - we got an approval.